# Click on particular column alone

Tags: apache-flex

How can i set click on particular column alone in Flex Data Grid... i want a click event for that column alone which should open a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the position of your column does not change, you can check the columnIndex from the DataGridEvent that is generated with itemClick.